# Plug in ZIF connector under laptop motherboard

Tags: laptop-repair, lenovo-laptop

I needed to do a repair of my Lenovo Thinkpad T440 and was able to take everything apart successfully but now I'm trying to put the thing back together. When the laptop is facing bottom up the keyboard and trackpad connectors come up to the motherboard right in the middle. However they're just long enough to reach their connectors and therefore not long enough for my hands to be between the motherboard and the rest of the case. The pictures in the linked post will probably do a better job of explaining it. Any magical ideas?
https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/540166-plug-laptop-zif-connector-under-motherboard/#comment-7154900

Comment: Electrical tape on some tweezers dont apply to much pressure and use something else to lock the clip. Im sure there are better tools but if you dont have them this is what I would do.

Comment: Did you check the [service manual](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t440s_hmm_en_sp40a25360_01.pdf)?